# Variable not going to list view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

I have a script where I want a string array to save and load again once the user has exited and reopened. However, when I re enter the app the variables aren't appearing on the list view where they are supposed to. I don't know whether this is because it isn't saving or loading properly or  that it isn't being sent to a list view. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class AltonDuel extends Activity {

private Button bt;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<String> strArr;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private EditText et;
ArrayList<String> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alton_duel);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int mm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int yy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int rideCountFile;
    strArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("AltonDuelCount", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    final Set<String> data = sharedPref.getStringSet("stringArr", new HashSet<String>());
   strArr = new ArrayList<String>(data);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            strArr.add(dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yy + "    |     " + et.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Set<String> data = new HashSet<String>(strArr);
            editor.putStringSet("stringArr", data);

        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: You are getting value `strArr` inside `onClick()` only.Here you have passed the `strArr` to the adapter before storing the values in it. try `setAdapter()` inside Onclick() after storing values to arraylist.

Comment: When the button is clicked the variable is added to the list view but I want those variable to be stored so when the user re-enters they are still there

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArr);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

twice? Use `setAdapter()` only after adding data to the array

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've moved that bit to after the data is added but it is still not working. I've updated my code in the initial question